# Avoid version conflicts while integrating Unity module to Android module

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, exoplayer

We tried to Integrate Unity module to Android project. In Android we are using `Exoplayer` for palying videos. We have a Unity module which uses `AvPro player` for playing videos. InBuilt, AvPro player uses `Exoplayer`.

The problem here was, when I tried to integrate Unity module to Android project, Android exoplayer dependencies were overwritten by Unity module dependencies. So In Android app we have method signature issues and version conflicts.

Is there any way to avoid these Conflicts ?.
    We are thinking that If Android uses its exoplayer dependencies and Unity uses its own dependencies, then we may not have these conflicts.

Any Suggestions were appreciated.